# Perl Multiple search and replace actions in one large text file

Tags: bash, perl

Given a set of replacement strings in a file `replacements.txt` like

```
s/string1/replacement1/g;
s/string2/replacement2/g;
s/string3/replacement3/g;
s/string4/replacement4/g;
s/string5/replacement5/g;
```

I would like to obtain the equivalent of

```
sed -f replacements.txt infile.txt
```

<strike>my file is so big that `sed` cant handle it, while I know that perl could do the trick.</strike>

Also the replacements are really a lot, and change from time to time. ( I need to run this a dozen of times)

Note that the replacements are fixed strings, so I do not really need those to be regular expressions.

*`sed` has problems only when the `regexp`  has globs and the input file is a single large line.*

Comment: 11G, it is all on a single line and that is why it was complaining. Although now I'm on a different machine and it seems I cannot reproduce the problem... anyway, is this possible with perl?

Comment: stupid question, does perl support the same set of "alternative" delimiters?
 example: `s@string1@replacement1@g`

Comment: Yes, it does: `perl -pe 's#a#b#g' <<<'aaa'` -> `bbb`.

Comment: So it works... but it fills all the main memory and swap space (100GB of RAM) :-(

Comment: I see. Is there no way to break the file temporarily into records while processing it?

Comment: I can try with a `tr` maybe, since it is a kind-of `json` file.

Comment: Sounds promising; please see my update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **`perl` equivalent of your `sed` command** is:

```
perl -p replacements.txt infile.txt
```

It should work with your sample `replacements.txt`, given that the `s` statements are properly `;`-terminated (note that `sed` would recognize the end of the line by itself as the statement terminator).

---

The **real problem, however, is that the entire large file is a *single line***, so the key to avoiding running out of memory is to:

- *temporarily* break that line into many short lines,
- send these short lines through the pipeline and perform the string replacements on them,
- and then re-join the modified short lines to form a single line again.

**If there's a character in the data that delimits records (units of data)**, in a away that doesn't interfere with the string replacements, **breaking the long line into multiple ones with the help of `tr`** is a viable approach; I'll use `}` as an example, because Kuzeko states that the data is JSON-like:

If you have ***GNU* `sed`** (Linux; verify with `sed --version`):

```
tr '}' '\0' < infile.txt | sed -z -f replacements.txt | tr '\0' '}'
```

Having `tr` output `NUL`-separated "lines" (`\0`) and `sed` read them accordingly (`-z`) is the most robust way to handle the chunking.
Unfortunately, the `-z` / `--null-data` option is not POSIX-compliant and the BSD/macOS implementation does *not* support it.

Otherwise (e.g., on **macOS**):

```
tr '}' '\n' < infile.txt | perl -p replacements.txt infile.txt | tr '\n' '}'
```

*Caveat*: If the single line in `infile.txt` has a trailing `\n`, you'll end up with an extra `}` char. at the end; to prevent that, add an initial `tr` stage to the pipeline that *deletes* the `\n`:
`tr -d '\n' < infile.txt | tr '}' '\n' | ...`

`perl` is still needed, because - unlike BSD/macOS `sed` - it preserves the trailing-`\n`-or-not status of the input's last line.